# Is it possible to create Custom Error Log in Apache 2.2?

Tags: logging, httpd, apache-2.2, errors

I'd like to prepend the vhost name in my ErrorLog and then pipe it into a program I wrote.

Is it possible to write Custom Error log format as it is with Access log?

Comment: Depending on your setup, you can have an ErrorLog for each of your virtual hosts.  It's not the same as a unified parsable logfile, but it's something.

Answer (score 8):

For piping see the [ErrorLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) directive and [Piped Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped) official manual entries which explain it pretty well.

Getting a custom error log format is more difficult. You can customize the access log easily with `LogFormat` but there is nothing built in for modifying the error log format. I did come across [CGI::Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html) which is a Perl module for outputting to the error log. Finally, there is always modifying the Apache source code directly depending on how badly you want this feature.

Answer (score 8):

In Apache 2.2 you cannot change the format of error_log easily - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog.

Apache 2.4 adds this support.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog.

Answer (score 6):

With Apache 2.4 you can use the `ErrorLogFormat` directive.

Syntax: `ErrorLogFormat [connection|request] format`

Simple example

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client %a] %M"
```

Example (default format for threaded MPMs)

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%{u}t] [%-m:%l] [pid %P:tid %T] %7F: %E: [client\ %a] %M% ,\ referer\ %{Referer}i"
```

Example (similar to the 2.2.x format)

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] %7F: %E: [client\ %a] %M% ,\ referer\ %{Referer}i"
```

Advanced example with request/connection log IDs

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%{uc}t] [%-m:%-l] [R:%L] [C:%{C}L] %7F: %E: %M"
ErrorLogFormat request "[%{uc}t] [R:%L] Request %k on C:%{c}L pid:%P tid:%T"
ErrorLogFormat request "[%{uc}t] [R:%L] UA:'%+{User-Agent}i'"
ErrorLogFormat request "[%{uc}t] [R:%L] Referer:'%+{Referer}i'"
ErrorLogFormat connection "[%{uc}t] [C:%{c}L] local\ %a remote\ %A"
```

Source: [ErrorLogFormat Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat)

Comment: Can anyone guess why `%a` would show up blank? It's supposed to be the client IP address. I [posted a question](https://serverfault.com/q/981195/161152) about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [mod_log_debug](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_log_debug.html).

Comment: While you are correct, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer at the link here, in case the link goes dead or is moved.