# Apache 2.4 ErrorLogFormat - How to show client IP address? - %a is blank

Tags: apache-2.4, log-files, ip-address

It appears upgrading from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 changed the format of the errorlog file. Error logs used to show the remote client IP address.

Apache 2.2 errorlog: `[Thu Aug 29 08:28:46 2019] [error] [client 50.57.61.20] message`

Apache 2.4 errorlog: `[Thu Aug 29 08:02:23.779174 2019] [:error] [pid 10036] message`

Benevolently, Apache 2.4 added the `ErrorLogFormat` directive. So I specified:

```
 ErrorLogFormat "[%{u}t] [%-m:%l] [%a] %M"
```

But the `%a` [format string that is supposed to](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) show "Client IP address and port of the request" is **giving me blank**.

Now the errorlog: `[Thu Aug 29 11:13:13.281770 2019] [-:error] message`

What I expected: `[Thu Aug 29 11:13:13.281770 2019] [-:error] [204.115.145.100] message`

The format string Client IP addresses are correctly showing up in the accesslog, which has a `%h` format string for "Remote hostname". There is no such format string for ErrorLogFormat.

We're running a dedicated Rackspace CentOS 7.6.1810 running, Apache 2.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

`%a` started working when we **updated mod_wsgi** from 3.4.18 to 4.6.2. Thanks to Fedor V. at WSM International.